# Как сделать так, что бы при срабатывании кода, менялись CSS свойства всех обьектов?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

День добрый.
Моя задача - сделать так, что бы при клике на кнопку, все элементы смещались вправо на 30%

Делаю я это так:

var a = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
a.style.left += "30%";

Но при срабатывании кода консоль ругается что нет такой функции как "left"
В чём проблема?
Как мне правильно реализовать мою задумку?

Comment: Первое предложение перед реализацией: не использовать смещение элементов left/right/top/bottom - только transform. Ну и было бы неплохо увидеть, что сделано, хотя бы минимальный код.

Comment: Потому что ты пишешь «+=« . То есть если ты ставишь +, ты прибавляешь к какому-то начальному значению. А какому? Чтобы ему получить: getComputedStyle(elem).left

Comment: Немного поменял код, но он всё равно не работает так как нужно. 
вот он: function movhtml() {
var a = document.getElementById("jmk");
var b = a.classList.item(0);
if (b == "0") {
var a = document.getElementById("jmk");
a.innerHTML = "←";
//меняем сиэсэс
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
e.style.left + "30%";
//заканчиваем менять сиэсэс
a.className = "1";}
else {
var a = document.getElementById("jmk");
a.innerHTML = "→";
//меняем сиэсэс
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
e.style.left - "30%";
//заканчиваем менять сиэсэс
a.className = "0";}};

Comment: `e.style.left + "30%";` простите, но Вы серьёзно? Решение вашей проблемы гораздо проще: `button.onclick = () => document.body.style.left = "30%";`